# Are the eigenvectors of a symmetric ${2 \times 2}$ matrix orthogonal?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have the following problem.

Given is a $A\in \mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2}$ with two eigenvectors $u,v \neq 0$.

> Does matrix $A$ have orthogonal eigenvectors?

Normally I would say no, because if you want a matrix with orthogonal eigenvectors then $A$ has to be symmetric and the eigenvalues have to be unequal.

Problem I cannot find a counterexample, so is there anything special with a ${2 \times 2}$ matrix?

Comment: If the eigenvalues are equal, then every vector is an eigenvector. Then one can pick a pair of orthogonal vectors, as well as many bases of non-orthogonal vectors.

Comment: What *exactly* is the question? In the symmetric case eigenvectors with distinct eigenvalues are orthogonal, which means that the only way to have a symmetric 2x2 matrix with two eigenvectors neither orthogonal nor parallel is to consider a multiple of the identity.

Comment: @Ian The question is about a statement, that if  a ${2 \times 2}$ matrix is symmetric, than you can choose orthogonal eigenvectors

Comment: Yes, you can always do that. You're not always forced to do so, if one of the eigenvalues has multiplicity greater than 1, but you can always do it anyway. This is basically a combination of the spectral theorem and whatever orthogonalization algorithm you like (e.g. Gram-Schmidt).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, but there is something special with the fact that the matrix is symmetric. Then, it follows from the spectral theorem that there is an orthonormal basis such that each element of the basis is an eigenvalue.